# Extension methods in Python

Tags: python, function, extension-methods

Does Python have extension methods like C#? Is it possible to call a method like:

```
MyRandomMethod()
```

on existing types like `int`?

```
myInt.MyRandomMethod()
```

Comment: sounds like "monkey patching"

Comment: I've had great luck with the method described here: [http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076194.html](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076194.html) I have no idea if it works on builtins though.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can add whatever methods you like on class objects defined in Python code (AKA monkey patching):

```
>>> class A(object):
>>>     pass


>>> def stuff(self):
>>>     print self

>>> A.test = stuff
>>> A().test()
```

This does not work on builtin types, because their `__dict__` is not writable (it's a `dictproxy`).

So no, there is no "real" extension method mechanism in Python.

Comment: It seems that an IDE can not offer any hints about any monkey patched methods since they only exists at runtime?

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with Forbidden Fruit (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit)

Install forbiddenfruit:

```
pip install forbiddenfruit
```

Then you can extend built-in types:

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse

>>> def percent(self, delta):
...     return self * (1 + delta / 100)

>>> curse(float, 'percent', percent)
>>> 1.0.percent(5)
1.05
```

Forbidden Fruit is fundamentally dependent on the C API, it works only on cpython implementations and won’t work on other python implementations, such as Jython, pypy, etc.

Answer (score 9):

not sure if that what you're asking but you can extend existing types and then call whatever you like on the new thing:

```
class  int(int):
     def random_method(self):
           return 4                     # guaranteed to be random
v = int(5)                              # you'll have to instantiate all you variables like this
v.random_method()

class int(int):
    def xkcd(self):
        import antigravity
        print(42)

>>>v.xkcd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    v.xkcd()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'xkcd'
c = int(1)
>>> c.random_method()
4
>>> c.xkcd()
42
```

hope that clarifies your question

Comment: But I mean calling directly on existing types, not MyInt, but int. So like v = 5; v.RandomMethod();

Comment: you can call class int(int), but you'd need to instantiate variable like: v= int(5)

Comment: Thanks. So in effect this class can be written several times with different methods and int will get all of these?

Comment: If you make multiple definitions like this, each one will inherit from the previous one, and so additional methods will accumulate in the most recently-defined "int" class.  But the classes defined along the way don't change (tho you lose your reference to them), nor do previously-created instances.

Comment: NB: this is almost always a bad thing to do in real Python code.  Unlike with extension methods in C#, here you are actually making the variable "int" refer to a completely different (inherited) class, which violates the principle of least surprise (i.e. suddenly isinstance(5, int) is False - WTF?)

Comment: @CarlMeyer Isn't this more like a reason not to use `isinstance`?

Answer (score 4):

The following [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) adds the method like Forbidden Fruit would without the limitations of it. Besides that it has the additional benefit of removing the extension method afterwards:

```py
class extension_method:

    def __init__(self, obj, method):
        method_name = method.__name__
        setattr(obj, method_name, method)
        self.obj = obj
        self.method_name = method_name

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.obj

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # remove this if you want to keep the extension method after context exit
        delattr(self.obj, self.method_name)
```

Usage is as follows:

```py
class C:
    pass

def get_class_name(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__

with extension_method(C, get_class_name):
    assert hasattr(C, 'get_class_name') # the method is added to C
    c = C()
    print(c.get_class_name()) # prints 'C'

assert not hasattr(C, 'get_class_name') # the method is gone from C
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to override the meta-class.  This allows you to, among other things, specify functions that should exist in all classes.

This article starts to discuss it:

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html

Comment: I don't think metaclasses give you any way to modify built-in types.