# When creating a wrapper class in python, how do I get the superclass's methods to return an instance of my wrapper class

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas

For example if I create a simple wrapper around a pandas dataframe:

```
    from pandas import DataFrame

    class MyDataFrame(DataFrame):

        def __init__(self,data):

            DataFrame.__init__(self,data)

        @staticmethod
        def add(a, b):
            return a + b
```

and then I instantiate it..

```
    x = MyDataFrame([1,2,3])

            x.add(1,2)
            #    => 3

            type(x)
            #    => __main__.MyDataFrame
```

it works. But, if I call a a dataframe method on it that returns a dataframe, It is no loger an instance of my wrapper class.

```
    y = x.reindex([3,4,5])
    type(y)
    #    => pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How do I get it to return an instance of MyDataFrame for all DataFrame methods? Is this a common issue? Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: I thought that was normal behavior.  The methods, unless overwritten just point to the place to get it.  Saves memory.

Comment: Basically, you can't.  It requires cooperation from the superclass.  The superclass has to be written in such a way as to return an instance of "whatever class I am an instance of", but many classes (like DataFrame) are hard-coded to return an instance of only that particular class.

Comment: you *can* overwrite the ``constructor`` property in the DataFrame class, but in general sub-classing DataFrames is not useful, try composition instead.

Comment: @Jeff: Composition is not really any easier, since you would still have to override every magic method to make your object act like a DataFrame.  The problem is that pandas is hard-coded to use only its own types, instead of parameterized.

Comment: @BrenBarn not since 0.13; can be easily subclassed, just override the constructor property as I said. the point is the use car for actual inheritance is very narrow and most reasons are much better served by doing has-a cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you have shown is not a *wrapper* but a subclass in Python. Now python subclasses and method resolution in your case behave by simple rules

1. Look at the `type` of the receiver object of the method.
2. Check the class hierarchy of the class and find the first instance the method is defined. Then look at the signature of that method and execute it accordingly. In your case, class hierarchy is simple subclass-superclass.

So, in your case,

1. `x` is defined as an object of class `MyDataFrame` -- simple. Obviously, `type(x)` is `MyDataFrame`, by definition.
2. During call of `add`, it looks at receiver object, which is `x` of class `MyDataFrame`. And this class in fact defines the method `add`. So, it simply returns the result of that method, Curiously, try calling `DataFrame([1, 2, 3]).add(1, 2)`. The result will be different since it looks at the `add` method as defined in `pandas.DataFrame` class.
3. Now comes the third part - Let's apply same reasoning. `reindex` is not defined in `MyDataFrame`. Where should we look next? Class hierarchy, that means `pandas.DataFrame`. Now `reindex` is indeed defined by this class and **it returns a pandas.DataFrame object!**.  (See this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) So, no wonder `y` is a `pandas DataFrame`.

Now I don't understand what you are doing by extending a pandas DataFrame in first place. Extending like this is not a common practice. If you provide details of what you want to do, maybe we can provide a solution.

**Edit:** Your original question is concerned with extension methods or extension objects (C# has them, and as you rightly pointed out, JS prototypes give you same functionality. Python does not have extension methods/objects as first class members. There has been discussion on that. e.g [python extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139111/python-extension-methods))

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I guess what I would like to achieve is be something like how in javascript I can add functionality to pre-existing objects by appending methods to the prototype class. Or,in clojure I can extend an existing type to implement a protocol where I have functions that will execute differently based on the data type they are passed. What is the idiomatic way to achieve this type of polymorphism in OO python?

Answer (score 0):

There have been several cases in Pandas where the classes have not been implemented well to form the basis for derived classes. Some of these issues are fixed, e.g., https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4271 and https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/60 .

It is possible to implement a parent `reindex` method so the result is a child subclass:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class DF():
    def __init__(self, data):
        print('DF __init__')
        self.data = data
    def reindex(self, index):
        print('DF reindex')
        return self.__class__(self.data)
        # return DF(self.data)  # not like this!

class MyDF(DF):
    def __init__(self, data):
        DF.__init__(self, data)
    @staticmethod
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b


x = MyDF([1,2,3])

x.add(1,2)
#    => 3
type(x)

y = x.reindex([3,4,5])
type(y)

z = DF([1,2,3])
type(z.reindex([1, 2]))
```

In newer versions of Pandas the `_constructor' is set internally to control the type returned. Setting this class attribute seems to do the trick:

```
class MyDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    @staticmethod
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

MyDataFrame._constructor = MyDataFrame

>>> type(y)
<class '__main__.MyDataFrame'>
```