# Spark copying dataframe columns best practice in Python/PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is for Python/PySpark using Spark 2.3.2. 
I am looking for best practice approach for copying columns of one data frame to another data frame using Python/PySpark for a very large data set of 10+ billion rows (partitioned by year/month/day, evenly). Each row has 120 columns to transform/copy. The output data frame will be written, date partitioned, into another parquet set of files.

Example schema is: 
**input DFinput (colA, colB, colC) and 
output DFoutput (X, Y, Z)**

I want to copy DFInput to DFOutput as follows **(colA => Z, colB => X, colC => Y).**

What is the best practice to do this in Python Spark 2.3+ ?
Should I use ***DF.withColumn()*** method for each column to copy source into destination columns? 
Will this perform well given billions of rows each with 110+ columns to copy?

Thank you

Comment: withColumns suffers from performance

Answer (score 2):

Another way for handling column mapping in PySpark is via `dictionary`. Dictionaries help you to map the columns of the initial dataframe into the columns of the final dataframe using the the `key/value` structure as shown below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, "John", "2019-12-01 10:00:00"],
  [2, "Michael", "2019-12-01 11:00:00"],
  [2, "Michael", "2019-12-01 11:01:00"],
  [3, "Tom", "2019-11-13 20:00:00"],
  [3, "Tom", "2019-11-14 00:00:00"],
  [4, "Sofy", "2019-10-01 01:00:00"]
], ["A", "B", "C"])


col_map = {"A":"Z", "B":"X", "C":"Y"}

df.select(*[col(k).alias(col_map[k]) for k in col_map]).show()

# +---+-------+-------------------+
# |  Z|      X|                  Y|
# +---+-------+-------------------+
# |  1|   John|2019-12-01 10:00:00|
# |  2|Michael|2019-12-01 11:00:00|
# |  2|Michael|2019-12-01 11:01:00|
# |  3|    Tom|2019-11-13 20:00:00|
# |  3|    Tom|2019-11-14 00:00:00|
# |  4|   Sofy|2019-10-01 01:00:00|
# +---+-------+-------------------+
```

Here we map A, B, C into Z, X, Y respectively.

And if you want a modular solution you also put everything inside a function:

```py
def transform_cols(mappings, df):
  return df.select(*[col(k).alias(mappings[k]) for k in mappings])
```

Or even more modular by using [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514068/extension-methods-in-python/514101) to extend the existing functionality of the `DataFrame` class. Place the next code on top of your PySpark code (you can also create a mini library and include it on your code when needed):

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def transform_cols(self, mappings):
  return self.select(*[col(k).alias(mappings[k]) for k in mappings])

DataFrame.transform = transform_cols
```

Then call it with:

```py
df.transform(col_map).show()
```

*PS: This could be a convenient way to extend the DataFrame functionality by creating your own libraries and expose them via the DataFrame and monkey patching (extension method for those familiar with C#).*

Comment: This is good solution but how do I make changes in the original dataframe. Here df.select is returning new df. I want columns to added in my original df itself.

Answer (score 1):

The approach using Apache Spark - as far as I understand your problem - is to transform your input DataFrame into the desired output DataFrame. You can simply use `selectExpr` on the input DataFrame for that task:

```
outputDF = inputDF.selectExpr("colB as X", "colC as Y", "colA as Z")
```

This transformation will not "copy" data from the input DataFrame to the output DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

This interesting example I came across shows two approaches and the better approach and concurs with the other answer. This is Scala, not pyspark, but same principle applies, even though different example.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
             ("1","2", "3"),
             ("4", "5", "6"),
             ("100","101", "102")
            ).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")
```

This is expensive, that is withColumn, that creates a new DF for each iteration:

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df) { case (df, col) =>
          df.withColumn(col, df(col).cast("int"))
          }
//df2.show(false)
```

This is faster.

```
val df3 = df.select(df.columns.map { col =>
          df(col).cast("int")
          }: _*)
//df3.show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dataframe.withColumn() which Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a noob on this (python), but might it be easier to do that in SQL (or what ever source you have)  and then read it into a new/separate dataframe?